# Eliminar registros que tengo en la bbdd

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, modal

```
function cargaPagina(pagina)
    {
      var desde = pagina * itemsPorPagina;
      $.ajax({
        data:{"param1":"dame","limit":itemsPorPagina,"offset":desde},
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"Conexion_Contacto.php"
      }).done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){

        var lista = data.lista;

        $("#miTabla").html("");

        $.each(lista, function(ind, elem){


          $("<tr>"+
            "<td >"+elem.id_contacto_empresa+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+elem.nombre_contacto_empresa+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+elem.telefono_contacto_empresa+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+elem.correo_contacto_empresa+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+elem.razon_social_empresa+"</td>"+

            "<td>"+'<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" class="btn btn-primary modalEdicion">Editar</button> '+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+'<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Eliminar</button>'+"</td>"+


            "</tr>").appendTo($("#miTabla"));

        });     


      }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,textError){
        alert("Error al realizar la peticion dame".textError);

      });

       /* Remove Item */
      $("body").on("click",".remove-item",function(){

        confirm('Eliminar Datos', '¿Esta seguro de eliminar este registro?');
        var id = $(this).parent("td").data('idpersona');
        var c_obj = $(this).parents("tr");

        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          type:'POST',
          url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
          data:{id:id}
        }).done(function(data){
          c_obj.remove();
          toastr.success('Item Deleted Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
          getPageData();
        });

      });
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que estás teniendo? En tu función `cargaPagina()`  usas variables que no se ven declaradas, ¿se encuentran en otra parte del código?. Dado que aquí intervienen varios archivos es importante  precisar dónde se encuentra el error con la mayor exactitud posible.

Comment: El borrado real de los registros se hace en el PHP del servidor. ¿Has comprobado que el PHP funciona? Luego pasa a comprobar que el ajax hace la llamada correcta.

Comment: En la línea `url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php'`, _puede_ que necesites meter un `/` entre `url` y `eliminar...`.

Comment: @A.Cedano el cargaPagina, lo que hace, es paginar la pagina

Comment: Remove Item
      $("body").on("click",".remove-item",function(){
        confirm('Eliminar Datos', '¿Esta seguro de eliminar este registro?');
        var id = $(this).parent("td").data('idpersona');
        var c_obj = $(this).parents("tr");
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          type:'POST',
          url:url+"eliminar_contacto_empresa.php",
          data:{id:id}

        }).done(function(data){
          c_obj.remove();
          toastr.success('Item Deleted Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
          getPageData();
        });
      });

Comment: a hora el boton me funciona todo bien, pero aun no me deja eliminar registro bbdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola:  A simple vista se ven dos cosas que no quedan claras...

1) La variable url en la función remove_item (como apunta @jotaelesalinas) parece no estar definida.

2) En la funcion remove_item tenes este código:

```
var id = $(this).parent("td").data('idpersona');
```

pero, en la función carga_pagina parece no estar definido:

```
  "<td>"+'<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Eliminar</button>'+"</td>"+
```

creo que debería decir:

```
'<td idpersona="' + elem.id_contacto_empresa + '">'+'<button class...
```

Te recomiendo siempre que puedas mirar el depurador del navegador controlando que variables realmente se envían al servidor.

Atte, Pablo.

Comment: a hora hice lo que @jotaelesalinas habia escrito y me sale el id, pero a hora como puedo eliminar ese dato de la bbdd. saludos Pablo